# why does clean.doLast not work but clean.doFirst work well in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm confused by these two gradle build scripts below:

1.

```
def allYouNeedDir = "$rootDir/all-you-need"

clean.doFirst {
    println 'do my job'
    delete allYouNeedDir
}
```

2. 

```
def allYouNeedDir = "$rootDir/all-you-need"

clean.doLast {
    println 'do my job'
    delete allYouNeedDir
}
```

The test result is the code snippet 1 can delete 'all-you-need' directory but code snippet 2 can't.

Both of them can output 'do my job', I think it means the task action has been executed.

Could someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task `clean` provided by the Java plugin is of type `Delete`. The method [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html#delete-java.lang.Object...-) of tasks of type `Delete` does not actually delete the passed files and directories directly. Instead, the task is configured to delete the files during its execution (this is called the *task action*). This is the reason why you usually don't need `doFirst` or `doLast`, as the task will be configured during *configuration phase* and do the actual deletion during *execution phase*.

When a task is executed, Gradle will first execute all `doFirst` closures, then all task actions and in the end all `doLast` closures.

Now, for your first code example, this is fine, because first the task will be configured to delete some files, then the files are deleted inside the task action.

Regarding your second code example, there is no `doFirst` closure. Inside the task action, the task checks which files to delete, but since the task was not configured, nothing will be done. Then, in the end, the task is configured to delete files, but since the task action did already run, it is too late.

---

There is one additional caveat. Both your code examples would work if the task `clean` was not of type `Delete`. Once your task is not of type `Delete`, there is no method `delete` in the scope of your task, so Gradle would check out the next scope for a method with this name. This scope is the scope of the `Project` instance which provides a method named [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete-java.lang.Object...-), too. As this method will delete the files instantly, both your code examples would work.

Please note that you could modify your code examples to use the `delete` method of the `Project` instance by changing `delete allYouNeedDir` to `project.delete allYouNeedDir`. Nevertheless I highly recommend against this workaround, as you should usually use task actions for file operations (e.g. for incremental build support).

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Körfer .What you said helps me a lot.I totally agree with your explaination.